# What does "laconic atmosphere" mean here?

Tags: meaning, h-p-lovecraft

It's from ["The Case for Classicism"](http://hplovecraft.hu/index.php?page=library_etexts&id=506&lang=angol) by Lovecraft.

> The first thing one remarks on reading his frigid “Engineering English” is its **laconic atmosphere** of aloofness from vivid feeling and from love of pure harmonic beauty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Laconic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laconic):

> using or involving the use of a minimum of words : concise to the point of seeming rude or mysterious

So basically, it's indicating this piece doesn't require a lot of words to express itself. "Laconic" also tends to imply that this terseness is intentional.